# Detecting new object on image

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, diff

## The goal

My security camera is constantly taking images and I would like to know when a new object appears to that image. (It is not actually a security camera but a camera monitoring packaging waste, but let's stick with security camera for simplicity).

Some examples:

- a cat walks in front of the camera – this should be detected
- the light conditions change (sun comes out) – this should not be detected
- a mild breeze moves the grass or leaves – this should not be detected

So in general, a new object should be detected, but changes in brightness or little shifts of the image in some direction should not.

What would be the appropriate way to tackle this issue?

## What I have tried so far

I am using [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) with Python, but this is not a requirement.

Based on [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/) I have experimented with two algorithms: Mean Squared Error and Structural Similarity.

This seems to be a good starting point, but is not yet precise enough. I have considered computing the edges of objects (using `cv2.Canny()`) and comparing those so that the changes in brightness would not effect the result.

Am I on the right track? Are there any other approaches / algorithms / libraries which I should try out?

In case I am on a right track, are there any extra steps I could take to increase the accuracy?

Comment: What you're looking for is typically called foreground segmentation. Here's the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreground_detection. If you don't care about where the moving object is in the picture, then Structural Similarity can work fine if you periodically update your background sample.